# Will my archer towers still defend me while they are being upgraded?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Let's say I'm upgrading an Archer tower and I leave to go attack someone. If someone is to  attack me while I'm gone, will my Archer tower still defend me while it is being upgraded?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I recall correctly, they will not defend you during an upgrade.

I couldn't find any documentation off of a simple google search, but [this strategy guide](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Flammy%27s_Strategy_Guides) has some good tips for a beginning player.

Comment: you are correct, only; camps, resource storage and one other building continues to work while upgrading.

Comment: @Paralytic The other one that still works while upgrading is the Clan Castle

Comment: The town hall still acts as a storage when it's upgrading (1000 of gold and elixir).